# How do I set a button to be selected for a specific duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I'm developing for iOS using XCode, and basically what the action my button is doing is I click the button, a sound plays for about 5 seconds, and the image of the button changes when I click it as well. So a sound plays and an Image changes at the same time. Here's the problem I'm having.

When I press the button the image changes for a second, and only stays changed if you hold your finger on it.

I have an outlet set up where I set

`button.selected= YES`

then

`button.selected= NO`

or "highlighted" in place of "selected" either way it results in one of two things. The new image that was intended to switch to on touch is now the "default" displayed, since setting it to "YES" first causes that, or it continues to do the same as above, only changing for a second.

Is there anything I can do to set the duration time of it being highlighted or selected to 5 seconds after being touched so that way it changes on touch and doesn't change back until the sound is finished?

-Extra stuff:
I'm using the Audio Toolbox framework for the sound code, and ARC is enabled.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the button to selected and then use Grand Central Dispatch's [dispatch_after](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) to deselect the button after a 5 second delay.

```
[myButton setSelected:YES];

double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [myButton setSelected:NO];
});
```

Comment: This almost works, but the problem is I want it to change on touch, stay changed for 5 seconds, then change back, so having the button deselect itself automatically won't work for me. Unless this doesn't take effect until the user touches the button, in which case I could try it.

Comment: I did some messing around and your method did the trick! I realized my problem before was that I had been putting my buttons image state method in the "viewdidload" area rather than my buttons action method. I just changed the parameters of your method to match my code, and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty much there.  You want to do the

```
button.selected = YES;
```

when the sound begins, but you don't want to change it back to `NO` until the sound is done.  You can set up a timer like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(soundDone:) userInfo:button repeats:NO];
```

and then implement the `soundDone:` method so that it simply sets the button to not selected.

However, I would highly recommend looking into your Audio framework and finding a more precise method of detecting when the sound is finished, rather than using a timer.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need, I just don't understand how to set button.selected= YES to only be true when it's touched, when I set it to YES my app opens with the Image it's supposed to change to as default, because the YES property acts like the image is already selected by default, I only want it selected on touch.

Comment: AH HA! I figured that part out so nevermind there. My stupid self had the selected property code under "viewdidload" rather than the button action! I'll continue to try out the rest of your method now!

Comment: This appeared to work, but "soundDone" causes an issue. The method for deselecting the image by timer doesn't have to perfectly sync with the actual sound file. If there is a method where I can set it to deselect via timer I can manually set the needed time. That way I don't have to worry about incorporating the Audio Frame work or screwing up the code that I already have.